# postgres group by with string_agg

Tags: postgresql

i have table emp_details having 5 columns

```sql
table emp_details(
emp_id integer,
emp_name text,
city text,
designation text,
designation_id| integer
)
```

```
emp_id      | designation_id| emp_name | city   | designation
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           |  35       | TOM   | chicago   |tester
    1           |  44       | TOM   | chicago   |developer
    1           |  57       | TOM   | newyork   |sr.programmer
    2           |  44       | BLOB  | newyork   |developer
```

now i want result like this from above data available in table

```
emp_id      | emp_name  |details
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1           |  TOM      |chicago-tester-35#developer-44,newyork-sr.programmer-57
    2           |  BLOB     | newyork-developer-44
```

Comment: How are you going to use that result? Maybe aggregating into a JSON value would be easier to process/parse later

Answer (score 0):

Recreating your dataset with

```
create table emp_details(
emp_id integer,
emp_name text,
city text,
designation text,
designation_id integer 
);
```

And data

```
insert into emp_details(emp_id,designation_id,emp_name, city, designation) values (1,35,'TOM','chigago','tester');
insert into emp_details(emp_id,designation_id,emp_name, city, designation) values (1,44,'TOM','chigago','developer');
insert into emp_details(emp_id,designation_id,emp_name, city, designation) values (1,57,'TOM','newyork','sr.programmer');
insert into emp_details(emp_id,designation_id,emp_name, city, designation) values (2,44,'BLOB','newyork','developer');
```

You can achieve your goal using the `string_agg` function

```
select emp_id, 
emp_name, 
string_agg(city||'-'||designation||'-'||designation_id,',') 
from emp_details 
group by emp_id, 
emp_name;
```

Comment: i have executed above query  in result set city name is printing two times if employee worked in same city with different designation then city name will print once and from above qury output is

emp_id  emp_name  string_agg
1  TOM  chigago-tester-35,chigago-developer-44,newyork-sr.programmer-57

but my requirement is if city name is duplicate for that employee print once
ex.
emp_id  emp_name  string_agg
1        TOM                 chigago-tester-35,developer-44,newyork-sr.programmer-57

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select
emp_id, 
emp_name,
string_agg(city_string,',') as details
from(
    select emp_id, 
    emp_name, 
    city||'-'||string_agg(||designation||'-'||designation_id,'#') as city_string
    from emp_details 
    group by 
    emp_id, 
    emp_name,
    city
) group by
emp_id, 
emp_name
```

By grouping two times you can make sure the cityname only appears once.

Comment: Thanks.. it work for me after small changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat_ws()` and then aggregate the result of that:

```
select emp_id, 
       emp_name, 
       string_agg(concat_ws('-', city, designation, designation_id), '#' order by designation_id)
from emp_details
group by emp_id, emp_name
order by emp_id, emp_name;
```

Output:

| emp_id | emp_name | string_agg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TOM | chicago-tester-35#chicago-developer-44#newyork-sr.programmer-57 |
| 2 | BLOB | newyork-developer-44 |

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4c7a2de782674b17c15d56bb65e8b301)